# How can I add these Firestore fields to a Dictionary?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swift5

I am looking to add all my "usernames" into a dictionary. I am having some trouble doing this. I am sure it's very obvious, but I am very new to coding.

I am stuck at, right now and can't seem to find a clear answer anywhere:

```
func fetchUser() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let usernameSearch = db.collection("users")
        usernameSearch.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error obtaining usernames")
            } else {
                for field in snapshot!.documents {
                   let field = field.get("username")
                    print(field!)
                }

            }

        }


}
```

I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me out. I am sure it's very obvious, or I'm just doing it totally wrong.

Comment: isn't it something like `for document in snapshot!.documents { document.data()["field"] ...`?

Answer (score 2):

First, get into the habit of safely unwrapping over force unwrapping. And choose more accurate names for your objects (i.e. `usersCollection` over `usernameSearch`). However, in this case, there's no need to instantiate individual properties for the database and the collection since they're not being used anywhere else but here (so be efficient and omit them).

```
var usersDictionary = [String: [String]]()

func fetchUser() {
    Firestore.firestore().collection("users").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let snapshot = snapshot { // unwrap the snapshot safely
            var usernames = [String]()
            for doc in snapshot.documents {
                if let username = doc.get("username") as? String {
                    usernames.append(username)
                }
            }
            usersDictionary["usernames"] = usernames
        } else {
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you actually meant an array of users:

```
var usersArray = [String]()

func fetchUser() {
    Firestore.firestore().collection("users").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let snapshot = snapshot { // don't force unwrap with !
            for doc in snapshot.documents {
                if let username = doc.get("username") as? String {
                    usersArray.append(username)
                }
            }
        } else {
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good useful comments. And Слава Украине!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that what you're looking for is an *Array*, not a *Dictionary*. I'll also assume that you are indeed getting the correct value that you'd expect out of `field.get("username")`, e.g. a string such as "Bob." Therefore, what you are trying to do is *map* the list of document objects to a list of strings.

If you scroll to the *Topics* section of the *Array* documentation from Apple, you can find some of the operations they provide for arrays such as `snapshot!.documents`.

One of those operations is actually `map`, and its description is:

> Returns an array containing the results of mapping the given closure over the sequence’s elements.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map

In other words, you provide a *transformation* to perform for each instance of a document belonging to the `snapshot!.documents` *Array* and get back a *new Array* containing the resultant values of that transformation.

In this case I will use a more specific operation; `compactMap`. We have to try and cast the returned value from Any to String. If that does not succeed, it will return nil, and we'll want to filter that out. I expect it to be an unlikely case due to the type requirements made by the Firebase Console, but it's good to be aware of it. Here is the example:

```
func fetchUsernames(from usernameCollection: String, completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let collection = db.collection(usernameCollection)

    collection.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
        guard error != nil,
              let usernames = snapshot?.documents.compactMap { $0.get("username") as? String }
        else { return print("Error obtaining usernames") }
        
        completion(usernames)
    }
}
```

The key line here being `let usernames = snapshot?.documents.compactMap { $0.get("username") }`. We are passing the *map* function a *closure*. This closure is passed an argument itself; each value from the `snapshot?.documents` array. You may refer to this passed in value with `$0`.